# A combinatorics identity

Tags: combinatorics, summation, contest-math

I happened to find this identity.

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{(n-2)!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot k^{k-1} \cdot (n-k)^{n-k} = n^{n-2}.
\end{equation*}

I got this identity when I tried to approach a Putnam problem: given $j\leq n$, prove the following: the number of functions from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to itself that satisfy for each $1\leq i\leq n$ there exists $m\geq 0$ such that $f^{(m)}(i)\leq j$, is $jn^{n-1}$. Here, $f^{(m)}(x)=f^{(m-1)}(f(x))=f(f\cdots(f(x)))$ is the $m-$th iteration of $f$.

When $j=1$, let $k$ numbers be mapped to $n$ before mapped to $1$. By some induction and manipulation techniques, I arrive at the above identity. (Later, I found $n^{n-2}$ is the number of trees with $n$ vertices and this multiplied by $n$, the choices for $f(1)$, exactly gives the number of functions for $j=1$.)

It is true for $n\leq 4$ as I checked. Any idea? Any connection to other theory? Really appreciate it.

Comment: Has it something to do with labelled trees?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Sorry I don't know the area of labelled trees. I got this identity when I tried to approach a Putnam problem, it asks given $k\leq n$, how many functions from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to itself are there satisfying for each $1\leq i\leq n$ there exists $m\geq 0$ such that $f^{(m)}(i)\leq k$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula

Comment: Does $f^{(m)}$ mean f composed with itself $m$ times?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes.

Comment: I've just checked it for $n\leq100$, so I believe it.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thank you!

Comment: @AnginaSeng Do you have any idea about how to prove this identity using labeled trees?

Comment: Try one of these links: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24k%5E%7Bk-1%7D%5Cleft(n-k%5Cright)%5E%7Bn-k-1%7D%24&p=1

Comment: I wonder about motivation of people voting for closing the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prove the identity $2(n-1)n^{n-2}=\sum_k\binom{n}{k}k^{k-1}(n-k)^{n-k-1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65636/how-can-i-prove-the-identity-2n-1nn-2-sum-k-binomnkkk-1n-kn-k)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is challenging to prove from scratch, let's do it! The given sum essentially is a convolution, which can be computed by extracting a coefficient in the product between
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^n}{n!}x^n \qquad\text{and}\qquad g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}x^n. $$
By [Lagrange's inversion theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2741758/44121) we have $g(x)=-W(-x)$ (with $W$ being Lambert function) and $f(x)=x g'(x)$, so the whole exercise boils down to showing that
$$ f(x)g(x) = f(x)-g(x)$$
which is pretty straightforward, since $g'(x)=\frac{g(x)}{x(1-g(x))}
$ follows from the fact that $g(x)$ is the inverse function of $xe^{-x}$.

Comment: I checked your calculations and it works. Thank you very much!